# C# ?? null coalescing operator LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, null-coalescing-operator

I am trying to prevent having NULL values when I parse an XML file to a custom object using LINQ.

I found a great solution for this on [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx), but for some reason it does not work for integers with me. I think I have used the same syntax but it seems I am missing something. Oh and for some reason it works when the node is not empty.

Below is an extract of my code.

```
List<GrantAgresso> lsResult = (from g in xml.Element("root").Elements("Elementname")
        select new GrantAgresso()
        {
             Year = (int?)g.Element("yearnode") ?? 0,
             Subdomain = (string)g.Element("domainnode") ?? ""
        }).ToList();
```

The errormessage is:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

If anyone has a clue as to what I'm doing wrong, please help :)

Edit: piece of XML (strange names but it's not by choice)

```
<Agresso>
  <AgressoQE>
    <r3dim_value>2012</r3dim_value>
    <r0r0r0dim_value>L5</r0r0r0dim_value>
    <r7_x0023_province_x0023_69_x0023_V005>0</r7_x0023_province_x0023_69_x0023_V005>
    <r7_x0023_postal_code_x0023_68_x0023_V004 />
    <r7_x0023_country_x0023_67_x0023_V003>1004</r7_x0023_country_x0023_67_x0023_V003>
    <r7_x0023_communitydistrict_x0023_70_x0023_V006>0</r7_x0023_communitydistrict_x0023_70_x0023_V006>
  </AgressoQE>
</Agresso>
```

Comment: My bet is on incorrect xml syntax. Can you show the xml content? The coalesce operator is right and if it wasn't it would not throw this error (it has nothing to do with strings)

Comment: Is the the `Year` or `Subdomain` assignment that throws the exception? You could try comment one of the lines to see if the exception goes away.

Comment: I have added a node of the xml to my post.
It is the empty node (starting with r7_) that triggers the exception. The code I have used to retrieve it is the same as what I have used for year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following extension method will return 0 both if the element is not present, the element is empty or it contains a string that cannot be parsed to integer:

```
    public static int ToInt(this XElement x, string name)
    {
        int value;
        XElement e = x.Element(name);
        if (e == null)
            return 0;
        else if (int.TryParse(e.Value, out value))
            return value;
        else return 0;
    }
```

You could use it like this:

```
...
Year = g.ToInt("r3dim_value"),
...
```

Or if you're ready to consider the cost of reflection and to accept the default value of any value type, you may use this extension method:

```
public static T Cast<T>(this XElement x, string name) where T : struct
{
    XElement e = x.Element(name);
    if (e == null)
        return default(T);
    else
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("TryParse",
                                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
                                    Type.DefaultBinder,
                                    new Type[] { typeof(string), 
                                                 t.MakeByRefType() },
                                    null);
        var paramList = new object[] { e.Value, null };
        mi.Invoke(null, paramList);
        return (T)paramList[1]; //returns default(T), if couldn't parse
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
...
Year = g.Cast<int>("r3dim_value"),
...
```

Comment: I have used your second suggestion. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

It is this expression which is throwing:

```
(int?)g.Element("yearnode")
```

That's because if the actual value of the element's text node is `String.Empty` and not `null`, since the empty string is not a valid format for `Int32.Parse`, the attempted cast fails.

If the  element is missing completely from your XML, this works as you expect, but if there is an empty tag `<yearnode/>` or `<yearnode></yearnode>`, you'll get the exception.

Comment: This might be the answer I was looking for. What would you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Where operator`

```
.....
.Where(a => ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).ToList();
```

Comment: What is `a` supposed to be here? Why are you calling `ToList` on what looks like an `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: No I can't, I do not want to filter the results, I just don't want my program to break when an empty node appears...

Answer (score 1):

If year is null or **empty** string that you will get an "Input string was not in a correct format" exception. You may write an extension method to read values. I haven't tested code below, but it may give you some hints.

```
public static ReadAs<T>(this XElement el, T defaultValue) {
  var v = (string)el; // cast string to see if it is empty

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)) // test
    return defaultValue;

  return (T)el; // recast to our type.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The message `Input string was not in a correct format` looks like the one thrown by `int.parse ()` so it could be that you have a `yearnode` with a value (not null) but which cannot be successfully parsed to an integer value.

*Something* like this may fix it:

```
List<GrantAgresso> lsResult = (from g in xml.Element("root").Elements("Elementname")
    let yearNode = g.Element("yearnode")
    select new GrantAgresso
    {
         Year = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yearNode.Value) ? 0 : int.Parse(yearNode.Value),
         Subdomain = g.Element("domainnode").Value
    }).ToList();
```

A couple of things to note:

`select new GrantAgresso` - you don't need parenthesis for a default constructor with object initializers.

`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` - was introduced in .net 4.0, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` if you're on 3.5 or earlier

`g.Element("domainnode").Value` - will always return a string

if you want a null for Year instead of 0, use `(int?)null` instead of `0`

Comment: Hi,

I have just double & triple checked my XML, the values I want to convert to int are either empty or a valid integer.

This is something I have also considered ;-)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a suggestion for dealing with the empties.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the cast from XElement to int? uses int.Parse method on the string value of the XElement, which in your case is String.Empty. The following results in the same error:

```
XElement x = new XElement("yearnode", String.Empty);
int? a = (int?)x; // throws FormatException
```

You can avoid this by first casting the XElement to string and checking if it is null or empty and only if not doing the cast to int?. To do this, replace

```
Year = (int?)g.Element("yearnode") ?? 0,
```

with

```
Year = !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)g.Element("yearnode")) ? (int?)g.Element("yearnode") : 0,
```

Its not pretty and will still throw if the string is otherwise not legal, but it works if you can assume that the element is always an integer or null/empty.